# List folder conent in Sharepoint with MSGraph v6 for Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to migrate from MS Graph SDK for java from v5 to v6 (6.3.0). In my v5, when I wanted to list folder in SharePoint, I had something like this:

```
client.sites(<site_url>).drives(<folder_drive_id>).root().children().buildRequest().get()
```

Now in v6 I don't have option to get "childen" after "root" and befre "get", so it's end up with something like this:

```
client.drives().byDriveId(<folder_drive_id>).root().get().getChildren();
```

which returns null. Does anybody know how to list this folder in v6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to access root drive item which should be supported with SDK v6 for java

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/drive/items/root/children
```

SDV v6

```
client.drives().byDriveId(driveId).items().byDriveItemId("root").children().get();
```